# Exporting and importing S3 method between packages

Tags: r, roxygen2

Disclaimer: I found the solution to this problem when writing this question. But my question now is "How does it work?"

I am trying to export S3 method from one package (say `pkg.from`) and import it into another package (say `pkg.to`). To export the method I use `roxygen2` comments.

```
#' @export
myclass <- function() {
  structure(NULL, class = 'myclass')
}

#' @export
print.myclass <- function(x, ...) {
  print('NULL with class myclass')
}
```

File `NAMESPACE` now contains both the constructor and method.

```
S3method(print,myclass)
export(myclass)
```

I believe that means both of them are exported. This supports the fact that I can call both after loading the package.

```
library(pkg.from)
methods(print)
# ...
# [130] print.myclass*
# ...
print(myclass())
# [1] "NULL with class myclass"
```

The problem is when I want to import this method into the other package using `roxygen2`.

```
#' @importFrom pkg.from print.myclass
```

During `Build` this message occurs:

```
Error : object 'print.myclass' is not exported by 'namespace:pkg.from'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'pkg.to'
```

If I don't import `print.myclass` it works even if I don't have package `pkg.from` loaded. [Hadley Wickham writes](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html) "you don’t need to do anything special for S3 methods". But I don't think importing a function is "anything special". Now I have more questions then I had when started writing this question.

- Where does R stores the methods available for every generic?
- How can one solve conflicts when he has installed more packages with the same method for a class?

Comment: I have the same issue. I want to extend an existing (base) generic in  package A. Just using `#' @export` does not seem to allow me to use the new method in another package B unless I list package A in "depends" of package B. I only want to list it in "imports", as is generally recommended.