# Importing a package's S3 methods without importing its functions

Tags: r, r-package, roxygen2, r-s3

I have the following dependency chain in a package I'm developing:

- My package uses a class (`trajectory`) defined in package A (`simmer`).
- It also uses an S3 method for that class (`plot.trajectory`), which is defined in package B (`simmer.plot`).
- I can import package A as a whole, but I cannot import package B as a whole, because it contains replacements for other functions defined in package A (the `get_mon` functions), so I get unwanted warnings about the original functions being replaced.

How do I use/import the S3 method without importing the rest of package B, preferably via `roxygen2`?

The `roxygen2` documentation [suggests the following](https://roxygen2.r-lib.org/articles/namespace.html):

> If you want to add a new method to an S3 generic, import it with @importFrom pkg generic.

For my example, this would be `@importFrom simmer.plot plot`, but this returns a warning that `plot` is not exported by `simmer.plot`. The same thing happens if I import the generic first, using `@importFrom graphics plot`.

Comment: What you quoted there is if you're importing the *generic* from another package, and adding an S3 method in *your* package. Have you tried `#' @importFrom simmer.plot plot.trajectory`?

Comment: I have! I got a warning that `plot.trajectory` isn't exported by `simmer.plot`, even though I can see that it is on its GitHub repository: https://github.com/r-simmer/simmer.plot/blob/master/NAMESPACE

Comment: Fair enough. That was just my best guess without having tried it. I was surprised you said it didn't work, so I did a quick search, and it seems like several others have ran into the same problem, all without **anyone** figuring it out! https://stackoverflow.com/q/23112762/8386140 https://stackoverflow.com/q/42952244/8386140 https://stackoverflow.com/q/32680169/8386140 If I don't have time to look into it and you don't get an answer, I might put up a bounty for this. Interesting question

Comment: Have you tried accessing the function with simmer.plot:::plot.trajectory()?

Comment: This doesn't solve this particular problem, because the overloaded functions are needed, as I stated in my answer below, but you only need to import a single valid function from a package and then the S3 methods registered there are readily available. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59667634/6788081

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iñaki Úcar's mention of the `@rawNamespace` tag led me to work out a version that doesn't import any of package B's exported functions, using the `getNamespaceExports` function mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24692264/12080622):

```
#' @rawNamespace import(packageB, except = getNamespaceExports("packageB"))
```

The `@rawNamespace` tag in `roxygen2` inserts raw code into the NAMESPACE file. `getNamespaceExports` returns the names of all exported functions in a namespace: this can be a package that you haven't attached.

For my specific example, I can write this:

```
#' @import simmer
#' @rawNamespace import(simmer.plot, except = getNamespaceExports("simmer.plot"))
```

which puts these lines in the NAMESPACE:

```
import(simmer)
import(simmer.plot, except = getNamespaceExports("simmer.plot"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51899220/import-all-the-functions-of-a-package-except-one-when-building-a-package)):

```
#' @rawNamespace import(simmer, except=c(get_mon_arrivals, get_mon_resources, get_mon_attributes))
#' @import simmer.plot
```

because you really need to use the overloaded functions in `simmer.plot` so that the plot methods there can work. An equivalent, but shorter version:

```
#' @rawNamespace import(simmer, except=getNamespaceExports("simmer.plot"))
#' @import simmer.plot
```

Comment: Thanks, wasn't expecting an answer from the `simmer` developer! Am I correct in thinking the overloaded versions are only needed for plot.attributes etc., not for plot.trajectory?

Comment: Yeap, that's right. If you only intend to use `plot.trajectory`, then your solution is just fine.